# DebugDiag Perf Analysis fails with error System.ArgumentException

Tags: windows, debugging, iis, debugdiag, debug-diagnostic-tool

I am trying to debug high CPU usage in an IIS app pool on a Windows 2012 R2 server. I have installed DebugDiag v2 Update 3 and collected dumps of the IIS app pool whenever its CPU usage goes above a specified threshold.

I was able to get 11 dumps generated - 10 mini dumps and 1 full dump. However, when I open the DebugDiag Analysis tool and load any (or all) of the dump files and do a PerfAnalysis, it always fails with the error System.ArgumentException, no matter what I try. I have tried to do this multiple times, and I still get the same error every time I try to analyse the files.

Has anyone been able to successfully do a Perf Analysis? I tried the crash analysis and it seems to work fine; it's only the Perf Analysis which errors out.

Here is the kind of error I see every time I try to do a PerfAnalysis:
[image]

Comment: Perf analysis is never a simple task, so merely a tool like that can break on itself, or report no useful information. If you don't know how to analyze dumps using tools like WinDbg, you might want to open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com .

Comment: @LexLi I haven't used WinDbg in a looooong time but found [this relevant MS blog link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/06/16/lab-19-debugging-a-high-cpu-hang-w3wp-process-using-windbg/), so thanks for the idea :)

Comment: Tess also has many posts on that, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/ So if you happen to hit a common issue, WinDbg can lead you to the culprit.